# C++ "Getter" method throwing access violation when trying to return private variable in same class

Tags: c++, get, private, access-violation

The problem I'm having is that the "getter" method in my code is throwing an Access Violation Exception whenever it tries to return the variable it's designed for.  I included the constructor below since the last line (the cout) does not cause an access violation.  LinkedNode is a header file.

```
#ifndef _LinkedNodeClass_
#define _LinkedNodeClass_

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class LinkedNode {
public:

LinkedNode(string first, string last, int ID, LinkedNode* rightNode, LinkedNode* leftNode)
{
    Fname = first;
    Lname = last;
    EID = ID;
    right = rightNode;
    left = leftNode;

    cout<<"LNODE EID: "<<EID<<endl;  //Does not cause access violation
}

int getEID()
{
    return EID;  //Does cause access violation
}

private:

string Fname;
string Lname;
int EID;
LinkedNode *right;
LinkedNode *left;

};

#endif
```

The LinkedNode object is being pointed to by a LinkedNode pointer called head.  Here's the code from the class using LinkedNode:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "LinkedNode.h"

using namespace std;

class MJCTree
{
private:
LinkedNode* head;
int size;

public:
MJCTree()
{
            head = 0;  //not sure how to null.
    size = 0;
}

void insert(string first, string last, int bEID)
{
    if(size == 0)
    {
        head = new LinkedNode(first, last, bEID, 0, 0);
        ++size;
    }
}

int getFirst() //This method leads to the Access Violation
{
    return head->getEID();
}
};
```

and the Exception:

```
First-chance exception at 0x013821f6 in Project 3.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcccccd0c.
Unhandled exception at 0x013821f6 in Project 3.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcccccd0c.
```

Comment: How did you declare `head`?  Did you allocate any memory for it?

Comment: I don't think you understand what Access Violation means. You are reading from an invalid memory location.

Comment: Added the full calling class.  As you can see, head pointer is in fact being created properly... I hope....  The MJCTree class is in a .cpp  The constructor is being called in the if(size == 0) block.

Comment: If you call `getFirst()` _before_ `insert()` you will get an access violation since head is null at that point and you are trying `return null->getEID();`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp  I'm not calling getFirst() before insert()...

Answer (score 2):

Your LinkedNode class looks ok, but your MJCT class is dangerous.
The getFirst method uses head, but there's no guarantee that head has been
initialized. The MJCTree constructor does not initialize it, and if you haven't
yet called insert, you'd likely get an access violation.

A class constructor should initialize an object and leave it in a state that is safe to use.  Your MJCTree constructor does not do that, because a call to the getFirst function will use a null (or previously uninitialized) pointer.  You could either modify the constructor so that it allocates a `head` node for getFirst to use.  Or you can modify getFirst so it is safe to call even though head is null, by adding a check for `size>0` or `head!=0`.  If that check fails you can't use `head` and either need to return an error or throw an exception.

We would need to see the code that creates an MJCTree instance and calls getFirst in order to tell exactly what is going wrong, but designing a class that can be used safely/correctly is more important.

Comment: Is there a special way to initialize a pointer to null?  I just tried setting head = 0; but that produced the access violation error.

Comment: That works, but that alone doesn't help avoid the access violation.  I've edited my answer to hopefully clarify.

Comment: I managed to fix my issue.  In the main.cpp, I was passing a MJCTree object to another function to insert items, but I'm used to Java, so didn't know I had to explicitly tell the compiler to pass by reference, not value.  So basically, I was inserting stuff into a MJCTree, then deleting that MJCTree.

Answer (score 0):

The *head* you mentioned should point to a LinkedNode object, so you must make sure you have do this action such as
    head = new LinkedNode(...);

Comment: more code added.  As you can see, I did exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you did not initialize your `head` pointer.

It might help to post more code, showing how you declared `head`, and how you are initializing it (or fail to do so). Remember that a pointer points to something, and if you did not initialize it, it points to, well, nothing, and accessing its contents

Answer (score 0):

Your LinkedNode class is perfectly fine.
You are calling accessor method on an uninitialized, destroyed or otherwise invalid `LinkedNode` instance at an address around `0xcccccd0c`.
A likely scenario, is that you did not create anything for your `head` pointer to point to, but it's hard to know more precisely without having more code to look at.

Answer (score 0):

The code you see is all correct, it was the code in my main.cpp that was the issue.  I was passing my MJCTree by value and not by reference to my insert function, which meant I never actually inserted anything into my tree.  Yep, I'm used to Java.